# Find first instance of non zero number in list after an index value

Tags: python

I am new to Python and having a quick snag. I wish to find the first non-zero index in an array AFTER an indexed value. Essentially, the array looks something like this

```
myarray=[x,y,z,0,0,...,0,a,b,c,...]
```

Can I change around the filter or next commands to accomplish this? I've seen on a post on here that one can use them to find the FIRST non-zero index, but I need to find one after the 3rd index (n=2). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one !

```
myarray=[45,45,1,0,0,0,8,6,7]

def firstNon0(_list,startindex):
    for index in range(startindex,len(_list)):
        if _list[index]!=0:return index
    return None

print myarray[firstNon0(myarray,3)]


>>8
```